# How to mirror GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, mirror

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an official github mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370239/creating-an-official-github-mirror)

How can I mirror a git repository to be shown on my page this way - https://github.com/ghc? I tried this: https://help.github.com/articles/importing-an-external-git-repo but it creates usual repository, not a mirror.

Comment: Try this? http://openhood.com/git/2010/04/09/mirror-a-git-repository-for-backup/

Comment: It still look like the usual repository...

Comment: This seems to be what you are looking for https://wincent.com/wiki/Setting_up_backup_(mirror)_repositories_on_GitHub

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that without Github's help: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370239/creating-an-official-github-mirror