# Mirroring git repositories. (branches, pull requests)

Tags: git, github

Assume I belong to two GitHub organizations. Org1 and Org2. Assume the same company owns Org1 and Org2.

I am actively pushing code and making pull requests to Org2/project.git.

Is it possible to mirror Org2/project.git to Org1/project.git so that all the branches and pull requests gets mirrored automatically when activities happens on Org2/project.git?

The reason is because we have Travis CI billing to Org1 and can't connect Org2 with it without paying for another subscription.

I have searched over stackoverflow and have seen some answers, however I would like this mirroring to happen live. Sorta like replication.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370239/creating-an-official-github-mirror

Answer (score 2):

As **[tweeted](https://twitter.com/paulcbetts/status/221070164056211456)** by Paul Betts, a GitHubber:

> Support@ is good for Anything you want to tell GitHub - bugs, features, high 5s; everything but security which go to security@

You should contact **support@github.com** and see if they will set up such a mirror for you.

Comment: Based on research.. The answer *is* to contact github and talk to them  They appear to handle mirroring on a case by case basis.  Maybe I should have said that....

Comment: Fair enough, but I would suggest including a link where you've read this, and quoting it in your answer!

Comment: This is also clearly stated on their Contact page: *"We’re here to help with any questions or comments. If you just want to say hi, that's cool too. (...) Feel free to email us at support@github.com"*